# DBIx::Class update Inflate column with function

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

I tried to emulate this SQL in [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) against the `update_or_new` function.

```
UPDATE user SET lastseen = GREATEST( lastseen, ?::timestamp ) WHERE userid = ?
```

It gives an error on inflate column saying it is unable to invoke `is_infinity` on `undef` .

```
$schema->resultset('user')->update_or_new( {
    userid => 'peter',
    lastseen => \[ 'GREATEST( lastseen, ?::timestamp )', DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1234) ]
} );
```

I guess this is because the `InflateColumn::DataTime` does not expect a function there. Is there any clean workaround for this issue?

Comment: Dump the SQL. Set the environment variable `DBIX_TRACE=1` to see a trace of what it sends. http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Troubleshooting.pod

Comment: It dies on Deflating / Inflating -- before trying to execute the sql.

Comment: It's DBIC_TRACE=1, but anyhow, DateTime->from_epoch(1234) is not proper. If you want to use that rather odd epoch, you need DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1234). `$ perl -MDateTime -E 'say DateTime->from_epoch(1234)'
Odd number of parameters in call to DateTime::from_epoch when named parameters were expected [...]
 DateTime::from_epoch(undef, 1234) called at -e line 1`  which is why inflate is not working because you are passing in undef since you are failing on the DateTime constructor

Comment: @mikew it was a typo in this question. I have edit and corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in DBIx::Class ( addressed here: https://github.com/dbsrgits/dbix-class/pull/44 ) and the fix is merged. It should be fine on the next release.
That said, if you're using DBIx::Class <= 0.08270...

You're using update_or_new, but the function only makes sense if the row exists already:
`GREATEST( lastseen, ?::timestamp )` lastseen is undefined if the row doesn't exist yet.

I read through the source+docs a bunch and cannot find a way to sidestep the `InflateColumn` code and still have bind values. You can pass in literal SQL with a scalar ref ( \'NOW()' ) but not an array ref.

Your best bet would be to use [the ResultSet's update method instead,](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#update) which does not 'process/deflate any of the values passed in. This is unlike the corresponding "update" in DBIx::Class::Row.'

```
my $dtf = $schema->storage->datetime_parser;    #https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#datetime_parser
my $user_rs = $schema->resultset('User')->search({ userid => 'peter' });
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1234);


#select count(*) where userid = 'peter';

if( $user_rs->count ) {
  $user_rs->update(
    lastseen => \[ 'GREATEST( lastseen, ? )',  $dtf->format_datetime($dt) ]
  );
} else {
  $user_rs->create({ lastseen => $dt });
}
```